# How to deconstruct and assign to class property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

## Question

I would like to deconstruct an object similar to this

`const {header, content} = this.data`

where data has

`data: {header: 'some header', content: 'some content'}`

to a class attribute so I can call

`this.header` or `this.content`

anywhere in the class.

## What I have tried

I was assuming it would be something like this

`{this.header, this.content} = this.data`

or

`this {header, content} = this.data`

but both throw errors.

## Conclusion

Is it even possible to deconstruct assign directly to class properties?

Comment: `Object.assign(this, data)` if those are the only two props

Comment: ^^ this, **if** those are the only two props. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What if its react and there are a bunch of props that I would like to assign to this?.

Answer (score 3):

You **can** do it with destructuring, because the target of a destructuring assignment can be just about anything you can assign to, but it doesn't really buy you much:

```
({header : this.header, content: this.content} = data);
```

*(Parens are only needed so the `{` doesn't look like the start of a block.)*

Live Example:

```js
class Example {
  constructor(data) {
    ({header : this.header, content: this.content} = data);
    console.log(this.header);
    console.log(this.content);
  }
}
new Example({header: 'some header', content: 'some content'});
```